# V-for loop in rendering HTML

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

I'm using the v-for loop for rendering HTML. I want to create one variable outside this for loop and want to use within th for loop while rendering HTML.

Using PHP, I can achieve the below scenario.

```
$messages = ["abc","abc","xyz","xyz","abc","xyz"];
$new = '';
foreach($messages as $val) {
if(($new == '' || $new == 'xyz') && $val == 'abc') {
    echo "--- ";
}
echo $val;
if(($new == '' || $new == 'abc') && $val == 'xyz') {
    echo " ---";
}
$new = $val;
echo "<br>";
}
```

**Output**

```
--- abc
abc
xyz ---
xyz
--- abc
xyz ---
```

How can I achieve the same with the vueJs.
I tried,

```
<div v-for='(message, index2) in messages' :key='index2'>
    <p>{{ message.text}}</p> </div>
```

Comment: you have to put same condition in "p" tag what you have applied in php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    messages: ["abc","abc","xyz","xyz","abc","xyz"]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(msg,i) in messages">
    <template v-if="(messages[i-1] == undefined || messages[i-1] == 'xyz') && msg == 'abc'">
      ---
    </template>
    {{ msg }}
    <template v-if="(messages[i-1] == undefined || messages[i-1] == 'abc') && msg == 'xyz'">
      ---
    </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you can create a `computed` property and generate the exact data you need then loop it inside `html`.